# Default CSS Design Difference between Form and Div Elements

Tags: html, css

Both `<form>` and `<div>` elements are block level elements. So, they are same design-wise and I can use form element as wrapper for everything inside it.

Based on it, I want to know, should I use Div as the wrapper for form element or work with form element itself!  Purpose is to add CSS to them.

Asked, as long back, I saw that when I used `<p>` as wrapper then everything was not same as `<div>`. Result at every place was not same even if everything same was applied to `<p>`.

Comment: There's no need to wrap a form with another element (such as DIV)

Comment: @Itay your answer is that it wont make any difference when applying css on form than when I used a wrapper and used same css there!

Answer (score 5):

It’s not too clear what you are asking, but to break down what I think the main jist is:

1. `<p>`, `<div>` and `<form>` elements have specific purposes and should be used for them. If you are creating a form, use `<form>`, a content block, use `<div>`, a paragraph, use `<p>`
2. Avoid unnecessary nesting of elements at all costs
3. If you are concerned about how the different elements are styled differently by default, use a [CSS reset like Yahoo’s](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) to ensure any styles you subsequently apply to any element are done so predictably and uniformly ([find a complete list of CSS reset files here](http://www.cssreset.com/)).

Comment: Not well explained. @Itay got it right at the comment.